# VSCode curly braces (brackets) not auto-completing the second one

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my VSCode 1.68.1, the auto complete after tab is not putting the second bracket.
If I type "{" it will auto-complete the second one "}". But if I tab for auto-complete it will only put the first one "{".

Gif:
https://i.ibb.co/TkjfdDG/2022-07-07-10-12-43.gif

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting then "[typescript]": { "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined" }
[check the image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psYkJ.png)

Comment: Still auto complete just with the opening bracket.

Comment: could you please send the screenshot of the text editor and emmet(write the emmet in search bar of settings)

Comment: prints:
https://ibb.co/z4P1Tnq
https://ibb.co/vYRsC6Q
https://ibb.co/rGJnTSZ